# Additional jQuery function in element

Tags: jquery

```
 var $panes = $('> div.page-groups', this);
 var $controls;

 $panes.each(function () {

   $controls = $('<div class="page-buttons clearfix"></div>');
   $(this).append($controls);

  //This is the line, I have a question about:

   $('.form-actions', $form).remove().appendTo($($controls, $panes.last()));

//more code......
});
```

I understand the whole line, but I can't figure out the function `$panes.last()` as a element in `appendTo($($controls, $panes.last()))`

Obviously this a condition check to see if it is the last pane?
How does this work?

Comment: Can you add more code to understand ? like the definition of your vars $panes and $controls ? and maybe a little extract of the HTML ...

Comment: `.last()` will get the last element in the `$panes` array-like object. It is not a condition.

Comment: $panes is a multi array object. So, if I understand this correctly then,  the element is attachTo to the $controls element found in the last pane element?

Comment: @ Karl-Andre Gagnon. You comment made me think. After spending more time today I got it sorted. Please answer the question so I can credit you with the answer.